# Вывод записей из БД в сетку

Tags: html, css, django, веб-программирование

В данный момент мой код выводит вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я хочу что бы текст был под каждой картинкой и всё выводилось сеткой по 3 записи в строке. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Мой HTML

```
 {% block content %}
    <div class="features">
        {% load static %}
        <h1>Игры</h1>
         <div class="alert alert-warning">
        {% if games %}
            {% for el in games %}
                    <li><a href="{% url 'games-detail' el.id %}"><img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{ el.image.url }}" width="200px" height="290px" style="margin:0 20px 20px 0;"/></a></li>
                    <p><a href="{% url 'games-detail' el.id %}">{{ el.name }}</a></p>
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <p>У вас нет записеей!</p>
        {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Мой css

```
    .alert-warning {
    background: #861a22;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
    width: 300px;
    border: transparent;
    display: inline;
}


.alert-warning a{
    color: white;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;

}

.alert-warning li{
     display: inline-block;
}

.alert-warning a:hover, .alert-warning a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в width: 300px; исправил и все работаает